# Class library making api call doesn't work in specific projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've got a class library for talking to a logging api server, the method "chain" is this:

Entry point ->

```
 private static bool SendChecksumToServer(Checksum checksum)
    {
        var res = _api.GetAsync($"Checksum?assemblyName={checksum.CurrentAssembly}&checkSum={checksum.LogFileChecksum}&fileName={checksum.FileName}");
        return _api.Deserialize<bool>(res.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
```

Which calls this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string apiCall)
    {
        ApiGet get = new ApiGet();
        return await get.GetAsync(apiCall, client);
    }
```

Which calls this:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string apiCall, HttpClient client)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(apiCall);
        return response;
    }
```

This works completely fine when I use the class library within a console app, but as soon as I move it to an actual application (MVC) it stops working, it doesn't even hit the controller action at all, I've tried everything I can think of like checking firewalls, making sure the async is correct (although I'm sure it still isn't because the api not responding freezes the app, but I can't bubble the async any higher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely experiencing a deadlock because of `.Result` blocking call.

> Don’t mix blocking and async code

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Refactor the code to be async all the way

```
private static async Task<bool> SendChecksumToServer(Checksum checksum) {
    var res = await _api.GetAsync($"Checksum?assemblyName={checksum.CurrentAssembly}&checkSum={checksum.LogFileChecksum}&fileName={checksum.FileName}");
    String data = await res.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return _api.Deserialize<bool>(data);
}
```

Ensure what ever is calling `SendChecksumToServer` also awaits the task,

and also not using `async-await` in the other calls if nothing needs to be awaited.

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string apiCall) {
    ApiGet get = new ApiGet();
    return get.GetAsync(apiCall, client);
}
```

*ApiGet*

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string apiCall, HttpClient client) {
    return client.GetAsync(apiCall);
}
```